# Is there a distance metric for dot product similarity that preserves the ordering of nearest neighbors?

Tags: metric-spaces, machine-learning

The dot product and cosine similarity measures on vector space are frequently used in machine learning methods. However, efficient data structures and algorithms often require a metric space distance function.

For cosine similarity, the angular distance defined as

$\displaystyle d(x,y)=\frac{\cos^{-1}(s(x,y))}{\pi}$ where $\displaystyle s(x,y)=\frac{x \cdot y}{||x||||y||}$

is a valid distance metric that preserves the ordering of nearest neighbors for any point. e.g for a set of points P and any point $p\in P$, if we order all points in P by its cosine similarity to p in descending order, then we would get the same thing compared to the ascending order of all points in P by its angular distance to p.

Is there a distance metric for dot product that has the same property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless you restrict yourself to vectors of particular norm $\|x\|=r$ (in which case the dot product similarity measure is essentially the same as cosine similarity). The problem is that for any two vectors $x,y$ that do not point in opposite directions, one can find a vector $z$ such that both $x\cdot z$ and $y\cdot z$ are very large (indicating large similarity).

To be precise, suppose that there is a metric $d$ of the form $d(x,y) = \varphi(x\cdot y)$ for some decreasing $\varphi$. Given $x,y$ that do not point in opposite directions, let 
$$z = M\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|} + \frac{y}{\|y\|}  \right)$$
where $M$ is to be chosen. Note that 
$$x\cdot z = M \|x\|\left ( 1 + \frac{x\cdot y}{\|x\|\|y\|}\right)>0$$
which can be arbitrarily large when $M$ is large. And similarly for $x\cdot y$.
The metric $d$ would have to satisfy 
$$ d(x,y) \le d(x,z)+d(y,z) = \varphi(x\cdot z)+\varphi(x\cdot z)  $$